# Cannot connect to remote mysql server 2012 from ubuntu 22.04 using frets or ms sql driver

Tags: 22.04, openssl, mssql

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04.
I then installed openssl, unixodbc-dev, freetds, and mssqlodbc18 using apt.
When I try to connect to a remote SQL Server I get an error. It is SQL Server Express 2012.

```
Error 20002 (severity 9):
Adaptive Server connection failed
```

I changed the *FreeTds.conf* file to include as below:

```
[sqlserver]
        host = XXX.XXX.XXX.X
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.4
        instance=XX_XXXX}
```

I also reduced the CipherString to `SECLEVEL=0` in the *openssl.cnf* file. However, when I try to connect it gives me the same error.

If I telnet to the server on that port, I can connect.

The same problem persists when I use pyodbc from python to connect and execute a query on the SQL Server instance.

I also installed Microsoft odic driver 18 and tried to connect using `isql` command with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Arjun, i'm having the same issue. I tried ubuntu 22/20 and php 8.0/8.2. Also tried pdo_sqlsrv, sqlsrv. Also tried freetd and didn't work. Using ubuntu it dons't work. But when i tried using pdo_sqlsrv on windows 11/PHP 8.2 it did work.